# Efficient resource mapping algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I have a set of resources R_1, ..., R_n and a set of resource types T_1, ..., T_m. Each resource can have one or more resource types. The mapping between resources and resource types is known, for example:

| Resource | Resource types |
| --- | --- |
| R_1 | T_1, T_2 |
| R_2 | T_2, T_3, T_4 |
| R_3 | T_1 |
| ... | ... |

A user can now request a number of resources by their type. For example, they can say:
*Give me three (different) resources. Two of those should have type T_2 and the third one should have type T_1.*

Is there an efficient algorithm that determines whether such a request can be fulfilled and which resource is used with which type?
I know that I can brute force all combinations, but I cannot find a more efficient solution.

Comment: You can reduce the search space by starting with the resource-types related to fewest resources. (That eliminates search-branches early)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You create a collection of your expected results, in this case you would have to loop your resources in order to find matches. If a resource matches a single expectation, then map that resource with the expectation and decrease the expectation's "missing" count.

If you find a resource that fulfills multiple expectations, then add it to a collection of "undecided items", that is, if it fulfills T1 and T2 alike and you still need T1 and T2 items, then make sure it is understood to be able to fulfill any of those and keep its belonging undecided until it becomes clear by either having enough undecided to fulfill both, or some of them being filled, etc.

Of course, you may have items fulfilling multiple such terms, 3 terms, 4 terms or even more.

In such cases, I would have a collection of undecided elements that fulfill those terms.

This way, by the time you've got enough matches for all your terms, you can fulfill them all and you will not even have to loop through to the end of your mapping.